# задача про продажи в марте

Tags: python

опять задача, только уже про продажи в марте, вот код моего решения что я пытался сделать:

```
n=3
a = [0]*n
sred=0
z=0
for i in range(n):
    a[i]=int(input())
sred=sum(a)/n
b=[]
for i in range(a[i]):
    if i>sred:
        print
        
print(z)
```

как вы видите нормального результата нету(его вообще нету)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В последнем цикле мы снова должны пройти по всему циклу `a` (можно либо через `n`, либо через длину массива `len(a)`), а затем добавить в массив `b` все дни, удовлетворяющие условию, через [`append()`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/list.append/).

В конце достаточно вывести полученный список `b`, в котором и будут храниться дни.

Comment: спасибо больше!)

Comment: @Дмитрий поскольку здесь не принято говорить "спасибо"  в комментариях, обратите внимание сюда [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Давайте посмотрим ваш код. Строки, которые вызвали у меня вопросы:

```
for i in range(a[i]):
```

Что вы перебираете? Если индексы списка `a`, то нужно это делать также, как в первом цикле - по `range(n)`.

```
    if i>sred:
```

Вы сравниваете индекс со значением? Нужно сравнивать элемент списка `a[i]`, а не сам индекс `i`.

```
        print
```

Это что? Хотите что-то вывести - напишите, что именно. Индекс элемента списка `i`? Сам элемент `a[i]`?

```
print(z)
```

Вы ничего не делали с переменной `z`. По заданию непонятно, что с ней должно было происходить. Тут выведется `0`, который там с самого начала и лежал.

Comment: переменная `n` присутствует в коде, просто автор неправильно вставит код